# jQuery Mobile programmatically reinitialise/restart app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing an app with phonegap and jquery mobile.

For handling unknown errors I need to completely restart my app and reinitialise all variables and dynamic content back to being the equivalent of the first run.

Originally I was just using $.mobile.changePage($'#home') which obviously doesn't work because it doesn't reinitialise any of the dynamic content or variables so I end up with double ups.

Is there a method I can call in jquery mobile to completely restart the app and set everything back to the initial settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a full solution, I think you are out of luck.

iOS definitely will *NOT allow the programatic killing of an app, let alone the programatic starting one.

Android does allow the killing of an app. Though undocumented (that I could find) you can use

> navigator.app.exitApp();

to kill the current app.

However, you still cant re-start it programaticly.

I think your best bet will be to write the code to reset the variables and local storage/DB (if used). Then reload the index page via `document.location.href = 'index.html?var=xxx';` where xxx = the current timestamp. Placing the timestamp at the end will ensure that it pulls a non-cached version of the page.

*Edit: Added *not* to my statement about Apple allowing app killing as it should have been.

Comment: nice tips both with `navigator.app.exitAPp()` and timestamping href.

Comment: I just got notified that a lot of people are reading this thread so I thought I would update a little bit. Killing the app caused problems with IOS and also causes problems if you are using cordova plugins that are active in the background so I actually ended up writing a manual reset function that goes through and sets all variables back to default. Not ideal or pretty but works well functionally.

Answer (score 4):

Try, document.location.href

```
document.location.href = 'index.html';
```

Comment: document.location.href = 'index.html'; not working in ios

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to [reload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) app?

> The reload() method is used to reload the current document.
>   The reload() method does the same as the reload button in your browser.
>   By default, the reload() method reloads from the cache, but by you can force the the reload to get the page from server by setting the forceGet parameter to true.

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restarting the app, you can check for the pagebeforeshow of a particular page and intialize to what ever values you want. so that each time you visit that page the values will be intialized.

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#PageID", {
     reverse: false,
    changeHash: false

});


$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#PageID',function(){

/* Intialise all your variables here*/


});
```