# Is it possible to programmatically restart an Ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to reboot my Ionic app programmatically.

I found solutions to only reload the current view like `location.reload()`, but I would like the app the re-run the app.js, both for iOS and Android.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37837377/1697755

Comment: If you are wanting to actually close the app and reopen it, I think you are out of luck; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707914/jquery-mobile-programatically-reinitialise-restart-app (see the accepted answer)

Comment: Not possible with iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recomend going with that approach, in single page apps always try to have a system to reset the data, cache, history, etc. and then go to the initial state, instead of forcing to refresh de webUI.
Ionic has a lot of features to help you accomplish that.

Comment: can you show the example of how to reload the app from start or forcefully close the app and restart with splash screen loading then initially `app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
var initialHref = window.location.href;
navigator.splashscreen.show();
// Reload original app url (ie your index.html file)
window.location = initialHref;
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

or you can hide your splash screen app.js inside

```
.run(function(){
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
          if (cordova.platformId === 'ios' && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {      
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
})
```